# XPath Select all children with specific parent node by attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, html-agility-pack

I want to select all children i.e images whose parent `div` with `id` is **testRoot**. The structure is unknown. I have simplified it here for understanding purpose. If it is XPath expression, that will be great.

```
        <div id="testRoot">

<div class="panel">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="/mafuae/en/p/1236018">
                        <picture>
                            <source srcset="/medias/sys_master/images/images/h4e/hf5/8820729217054/NikonSlr-H-Tablet.jpg" media="(min-width: 768px)">
                            <img src="" alt="NikonSlr_H_Desktop.jpg">
                        </source>
                        </source></source></picture>
                    </a>
                </div>
            <div class="panel">
                    <a tabindex="-1" href="/mafuae/en/storespromotions">
                        <picture>
                            <source srcset="/medias/sys_master/images/images/h73/hd7/8818984321054/Ramadan2-14thMay-Tablet.jpg" media="(min-width: 768px)">
                            <img src="" alt="Ramadan2_14thMay_Desktop.jpg">
                        </source></source></source></picture>
                    </a>
                </div>
</div>
```

This is what i tried but...

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='hero']/div/div")
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For the `div` element with an `id` attribute of `hero` `//div[@id='hero']`, these XPath expression will select elements as follows:

- `//div[@id='hero']/*` will select all of its **children** elements.
- `//div[@id='hero']/img` will select all of its **children**  `img` elements.
- `//div[@id='hero']//*` will select all of its **descendent** elements.
- `//div[@id='hero']//img` will select all of its **descendent** `img` elements.

Comment: i did it in a long way but you made it simpler for me :). `//div[@id='hero']//img` is the code i was looking for